Charged for refused shipment, seller won't respond. Any recourse?
I bought something from what I now believe to be a fraudulent UK seller "S" (I'm in the US). When they never shipped the order (~45 days later), I filed a claim with my credit card ("A"), which initially resulted in the charge being reversed.
"A" contacted the UK bank which handled the transaction, "B", which sent a letter to "S" informing them of the charge-back and inviting "S" to submit evidence for the transaction.
In response to receiving said notice, "S" mailed... something. They sent a photocopy of the mailing label, which happens to be post-marked the same date as their response to "B" but the photocopy is conveniently cropped so that this wasn't obvious.
Since the charge had been reversed at the time the shipment arrived at my residence, I refused delivery.
"B" is rejecting the charge-back, and "A" is now declining to investigate further and saying they "don't have permission to initiate a charge back" or something of that nature. Meanwhile, "S" has never responded to any of my communication attempts, and "A" is saying "S" is now not responding to them, either. "S" has my money and I have nothing. This situation smells rotten.
Do I have any recourse?
(Just to make things even more interesting, my card was hit with a couple completely-fraudulent charges the day after the claim was first closed. Might be unrelated, but the timing is suspicious.)

File a new dispute, explain to the bank that whatever they shipped never arrived, and let them deal with that. If S refuses to respond to the credit card payment processor they'll charge them back by default.

@littleadv Sounds like an answer, not a comment.

@littleadv, if you read more carefully, you'll see I mention that my bank is refusing to issue a charge-back.

@Matthew they don't have a say in the matter. I don't understand what it is that they are refusing. Your previous dispute was resolved because you claimed the item wasn't shipped and the seller provided a proof of shipment. You have a new dispute now - that shipment was never delivered. You need to check what "refused delivery" actually means though. It may be considered as a return, which may not be allowed based on the terms of the sale.

@littleadv, "refused delivery" means I told the package carrier (USPS) "I refuse this delivery". Seller's site says "returns are accepted within a 7 day period from receiving the item".

Dispute it is then. The other alternative is a lawsuit, which may be difficult given you're in a different country from the seller.

The "something of that nature" part is important, so may be worth editing your question with more detail.
(You also don't need to protect the identity of your credit card company. It's either Visa, MasterCard, AmEx, or Discover.)
If they are the credit card company they don't need the "permission" of the vendor to get their money back. Call your credit card company and insist that your original claim still stands: you did not receive the merchandise you ordered and are requesting a refund.
Do not complicate the issue by mentioning photocopies of labels, doctored/cropped photos, or refusing shipments of odd packages.
It's your word against the seller's, but this is a purchaser protection benefit you're asking for.
If there's a third-party processor involved here, like PayPal or similar, it might get more complicated. Let us know if that's the case.
The amount of money involved may also be important. For $20 your card company might decide it's not worth their time to argue further, but I suspect it's somewhat more than that since they seem to be reluctant to just refund your money.

AmEx and Discover might have only one issuing bank. Visa and MC have many. Capital One, for example, is a well known issuer of Visa cards. Honestly, I'm not that worried about disclosing the bank, but... principle.  Unfortunately, I don't recall the exact words of the agent I talked to, but it was something like "we don't have an agreement to issue a charge-back". Also, I did mention that there are multiple parties involved; at least the seller, payment processor, UK bank, US bank, and myself.

I think the problem is that my bank ("A") is being charged by a (well known and definitely legit) UK bank ("B"), and "B" is denying the claim, so my bank doesn't have a direct say. It's not a crippling amount (~$120), but enough that I Am Not Amused. I've also tried contacting "B" (it's already the weekend for them, so not expecting a reply yet), but I'm not sure I know the right channels, and (for hopefully-obvious reasons) I don't want to be trying to argue with a bank on an international call.

@Matthew What happens with the networks (Visa and MasterCard) is the issuing (your) bank and the acquiring (merchant's) bank try to come to an agreement over chargebacks. In the case they disagree, the dispute can be raised to Visa/MC which then makes a decision, called arbitration. The correct channel is to continue to dispute it with your own bank.
